# How to run program (not shortcut) As Administrator always in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

There is bunch of articles on internet to how setup a program `shortcut` to run as administrator. also how to run everything as administrator.

neither of above apply to my question.

In windows 7 you could setup actual .exe file property (Compatibility tab in Properties) to Run As Administrator.

That what I am trying to do in Windows 10. **Is it possible?**

*Why do I want it. I need to run Visual Studio as admin. If I setup the shortcut then I cant use the right-click -> Recent files... So I have to right-click, select Visual Studio, wait till it open, use Recent files inside VS.. Takes twice as long..*

**EDIT** Found the solution here: [How can I make a program permanently run as admin when the Compatibility tab is missing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1086855/why-some-programs-dont-have-compatibility-tab-in-the-properties?noredirect=1#comment1538253_1086855)

[image: There is no Compatibility tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the actual .exe File**

Navigate to your C drive

Find your Program Folder

Right Click on the .exe File

Go to Properties

Tick the "Run as Administrator" box

Click Save.

**For the Programs Shortcut**

Right click the shortcut

Go to Properties

Tick the "Run as Administrator Box"

Click save.

This is the same as it has been in windows 7.

Edit Adding this photo here to show you that it's the same for windows 10.

[image]

Comment: I asked wrong question.. actually now there are 2 types of programs. Visual Studio doesn't have "Compatibility" tab where you can tick Run As Administrator... I should've narrowed it.