# How can I make a program permanently run as admin when the Compatibility tab is missing?

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, if I open properties of devenv.exe (Visual Studio 2015) there is no way I can set the "Run As Administrator".. But some other programs still have tab "Compatibility" in their properties where you can do that..

**Whats the difference? And is there a way to set Run As Administrator on devenv.exe ?**

[image]

Comment: Is there a troubleshoot compatibility button? if you right click the .exe, is there an option to troubleshoot compatibility? if so then refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8

Comment: yes there is.. and I found the way to fix.. please write it as an answer. ill mark it. thanks!

Comment: When you create a shortcut, you don’t have to rely on the Troubleshooting tab: Use the [Advanced Properties dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s5OGC.png).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the .exe and there should be an option to Troubleshoot Compatibility. 
This worked for me last time i ran into this on Win10.

**EDIT** 
 
 
I'm not at my Windows 10 box now, but found the step by step instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257110/can-you-force-visual-studio-to-always-run-as-an-administrator-in-windows-8)

1. right-click devenv.exe and select "Troubleshoot compatibility".
2. select "Troubleshoot program"
3. check "The program requires additional permissions"
4. click "Next", click "Test the program..."
5. wait for the program to launch
6. click "Next"
7. select "Yes, save these settings for this program"
8. click "Close"

Comment: yeah. would you please describe the steps to make it run as administrator for ever?

Comment: I'm not on my window 10 box now, but found the step-by-step. See edits in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a exe does not have a compatibility tab one option is to just make a new shortcut to the exe and use that instead, then in the shortcut you can click the "Advanced" button and check the box for "Run as administrator".

[image]

This will not make projects launched with a double click administrator but any time you launch Visual Studio manually it will be elevated from that point on. (This is the process I personally use for my Visual Studio)

Comment: It’s unlikely the shortcut will have the accessibility tab when the `.exe` doesn’t. There are multiple reasons why it may not be visible, like a x64 `.exe`. That’s obviously not the case with Visual Studio, though.

Comment: @DanielB you are correct, I had the steps after you make the shortcut slightly wrong. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: the question is about .exe not shortcuts.. shortcuts are obvious.

Comment: @BoppityBop I know, but you would be surprised how often can forget that it is easy to make a shortcut. That being said, I still think the accepted answer is the better answer, I just wanted to provide a potential alternative.

Comment: I disagree that this is "obvious" - it is  a useful workaround. I had this exact case where the shortcut DID allow me to set to run as admin, but the main EXE did not have the compat tab.